# FrameBuffer to file inside libgdx or OpenGL

Tags: file, png, screenshot, libgdx

I am trying to take screenshots in the most efficient way. I thing using a FrameBuffer is the most efficient way of taking screenshots because i can process the data in different thread than rendering thread. 
How can i get the information from FrameBUffer and transfer it to a file?

```
FrameBuffer m_fbo;

render(){
   m_fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB565, (int)(w * m_fboScaler), (int)(h * m_fboScaler), false);
   m_fboRegion = new TextureRegion(m_fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
   m_fboRegion.flip(false, true);
   m_fbo.begin();
   ...rendering...
   m_fbo.end();
   writeTextureRegionToFile(); - i need some lines of code for the implementation of this method
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `FrameBuffer` contents reside in memory managed by OpenGL, so you will (as far as I understand things) still need to fetch those bytes using OpenGL APIs on the render thread.  Specifically, you want [the `ScreenUtils` class](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ScreenUtils.html)
to get a `byte[]` containing the `RGBA8888` contents of your `FrameBuffer`.

Once you get the raw bytes, you can do any compression/conversion/output on a different thread, of course.  There is a [forum post](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=8358#p8358) that has a quick and dirty PNG writer.  The Libgdx-specific (?) `CIM` format is also an option (see the [`PixmapIO` class](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/PixmapIO.html)), but you'll have to convert the bytes into a `Pixmap` first.

Comment: "still need to fetch those bytes using OpenGL APIs on the render thread" - by doing that fps drops to 6. If this could be done in separate thread would be usefull.

Comment: Libgdx (and LWJGL underneath) only allow a single thread to do OpenGL calls, so there isn't much hope of getting it off the render thread.